# How to reuse _ViewImports.cshtml in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, tag-helpers

I have three projects:

1. WebBase => this project contains `_ViewImports.cshtml` and is an RCL project.
2. Galleries => this project is a module, that uses `WebBase` for some common base things, and also contains items related to galleries. And it is also an RCL project.
3. SiteBuilder => this is my orchestrator project, that combines all modules together in one panel.

Now, the problem is that my `_ViewImports.cshtml` which is in `WebBase` is not recognized by compiler in my `Galleries` project. Thus my `<partial>` tags are not rendered. And I have to copy/paste that `_ViewImports.cshtml` to the `Galleries` projects too.

How can I reuse `_ViewImports.cshtml`?

Comment: [Add as a Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963750/add-file-as-a-link-on-visual-studio-debug-vs-publish) still working on vs 2019

Comment: Add as a link does not work for this purpose. I tested and it failed.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the _ViewImports.cshtml file is to provide a mechanism to make directives available to Razor pages globally in one project so that you don't have to add them to pages individually. Therefore, you cannot share them across multiple projects.